# Is my H2O cluster version incompatible with h2oEnsemble 1.9, or what causes this "Naive Bayes" error when no Bayesian function is being used?

Tags: r, h2o

The `h2oEnsemble` library's author, Dr. LeDell, suggested checking out v1.9 from the h2o-3 GitHub repo to work around a problem I and others encountered, which is described in [this](https://community.h2o.ai/questions/1588/issue-with-dl-h2o-ensembles-and-h2o-last-version.html) thread.

This led to a different error in my case, where only the unmodified wrappers can be used with `h2oEnsemble::h2o.ensemble()`.

For instance, learners like this will work:

```
learner <- c("h2o.deeplearning.wrapper", "h2o.randomForest.wrapper", "h2o.glm.wrapper")
```

But anything custom like this:

```
h2o.glm.2 <- function(..., alpha = 0.5) h2o.glm.wrapper(..., alpha = alpha)
learner <- c("h2o.glm.2") 

ens2 <- h2o.ensemble(x             = setdiff(colnames(train), "y"),
                    y              = "y",
                    training_frame = trainHex,
                    metalearner    = "h2o.deeplearning.wrapper",
                    learner        = learner)
```

throws this error:

> ```
> Error in h2o.ensemble(x = setdiff(colnames(train), "y"), y = "y", training_frame = trainHex, :
> The Naive Bayes function does not support regression, please remove this function from your set of base learners
> ```

Dr. LeDell suggested to confirm compatibility through her compatibility table on GitHub and to move further questions to StackOverflow (because they are shutting down their forum).

It seems that v1.9 is not on that table though and my H2O cluster version is also newer than what was listed there. Does anyone have anecdotal knowledge of which H2O clusters will work with v1.9 of the R package?

```
> h2o.getVersion()
```

> "3.10.0.2"

Update: I tried upgrading to 3.12 and 3.13, but encountered the same error with this. Though I did notice that `h2o::h2o.stackedEnsemble()` works in 3.13.

**Update:**

The package author suggested version 3.10.5.2 in the comments/updated question. I tried updating to that, but sadly the problem still occurred. Here's my cluster info after the update:

```
> h2o.init(nthreads = -1)
```

> ```
>  Connection successful!
>
> R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
>     H2O cluster uptime:         2 minutes 28 seconds 
>     H2O cluster version:        3.10.5.2 
>     H2O cluster version age:    15 days  
>     H2O cluster name:           hackr 
>     H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
>     H2O cluster total memory:   16.98 GB 
>     H2O cluster total cores:    24 
>     H2O cluster allowed cores:  24 
>     H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
>     H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
>     H2O Connection port:        54321 
>     H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
>     H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
>     R Version:                  R version 3.4.0 Patched (2017-05-19 r72713)
> ```

*Doesn't work with custom learner:*

```
h2o.glm.2 <- function(..., alpha = 0.5) h2o.glm.wrapper(..., alpha = alpha)
learner <- c("h2o.glm.2", "h2o.deeplearning.wrapper", "h2o.randomForest.wrapper", "h2o.glm.wrapper")

ens <- h2o.ensemble(x              = setdiff(colnames(train), "y"),
                    y              = "y",
                    training_frame = trainHex,
                    metalearner    ="h2o.randomForest.wrapper",
                    learner        = learner)
summary(ens)
```

> Error in h2o.ensemble(x = setdiff(colnames(train), "y"), y = "y",
>   training_frame = trainHex,  :    The Naive Bayes function does not
>   support regression, please remove this function from your set of base
>   learners.

*but works with only default wrapper learners:*

```
learner <- c("h2o.deeplearning.wrapper", "h2o.randomForest.wrapper", "h2o.glm.wrapper")

ens <- h2o.ensemble(x              = setdiff(colnames(train), "y"),
                    y              = "y",
                    training_frame = trainHex,
                    metalearner    ="h2o.randomForest.wrapper",
                    learner        = learner)
summary(ens)
```

R package version is `h2o_3.10.5.2`.

Answer (score 0):

**h2oEnsemble** v0.1.9 package has not been officially released yet, but it's on the "h2oEnsemble_v0.1.9" branch [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/tree/h2oEnsemble_v0.1.9/h2o-r/ensemble).  On the README for that branch, the updated table shows that it will be compatible with H2O >=3.10.1.*.

It looks like you are doing a regression problem and attempting to use the `h2o.naiveBayes.wrapper()` function?  The error message tells you that can't use Naive Bayes on a regression problem (Naive Bayes is a classification algorithm and does not support regression).

Using the "h2oEnsemble_v0.1.9" branch version of **h2oEnsemble** and the latest stable release of H2O, 3.10.5.2, I can replicate your error using the code below, but all you need to do to fix it is remove the Naive Bayes model from your base learners:

```
library(h2oEnsemble)  # Install from h2oEnsemble_v0.1.9 branch
h2o.init()

# Import a sample binary outcome train/test set into R
train <- h2o.importFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_train_5k.csv")
test <- h2o.importFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_test_5k.csv")
y <- "response"
x <- setdiff(names(train), y)
family <- "gaussian"


# Specify the base learner library & the metalearner
learner <- c("h2o.glm.wrapper", "h2o.randomForest.wrapper", 
             "h2o.gbm.wrapper", "h2o.naiveBayes.wrapper")
metalearner <- "h2o.glm.wrapper"

# Train the ensemble 
fit <- h2o.ensemble(x = x, y = y, 
                    training_frame = train, 
                    family = family, 
                    learner = learner, 
                    metalearner = metalearner)
```

Comment: Hi Dr. LeDell. Thanks so much. I am on H2O 3.10. The error message is thrown for any custom learner, even just a single GLM or randomForest. I can show some reproducible code. Shall I close this as answered (as to which versions are compatible) and continue troubleshooting the problem in a separate question, or handle both here?

Comment: An update: I tried upgrading to 3.12 and 3.13, but encountered the same error.

Comment: I see that you've updated your question to include that you were using 3.10.0.2, which is actually compatible with h2oEnsemble 0.1.8, not 0.1.9.  For now, you can use 3.10.5.2 or the latest stable, 3.10.5.3.  I have verified above that that version 3.10.5.2 is compatible (and .3 also works). https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-vajda/3/index.html

Comment: Great, thank you, I will try that presently. Yea, I left a comment above about my version then came back later and made a corresponding edit. Got your update. I will try those versions today and report back. Thanks again for your help; much appreciated.

Comment: **Update**: I'm sorry to report that the problem persists on version 3.10.5.2. I will update my question with the details. I made sure to fully restart everything after the installation, and all seems to work except for custom learners in `h2o.ensemble`.

Comment: **h2oEnsemble** 0.1.9 is now released, this should fix all your issues.  It's not merged into master yet: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/pull/1376  but the source is here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/h2o-ensemble/R/h2oEnsemble_0.1.9.tar.gz

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much; I'll try it today.